# Remove a screw stripped head with the reverse and hammer function of a power drill, instead of a lefthanded drill bit?

Tags: screws, powertools

I just learned about left-handed drill bits that can be used to removed screws with stripped heads. However, without those lefthanded drill bits available, can I use the normal (right-handed) drill bits, and the Reverse function of the power drill to undo a screw with stripped head?

My DeWalt power drill/hammer/driver has the Hammer function, so combining with the Reverse function, it would additionally help?

Answer (score 3):

> can I use the normal (right-handed) drill bits, and the Reverse
> function of the power drill to undo a screw with stripped head?

NO it will not grab onto the head.

The reason the reverse bit *may* work is because the cutting part of the bit is designed to cut into the surface, when it starts to  cut or grab it then turns the screw counter clockwise.

A normal bit will just spin and not "grab".

> My DeWalt power drill/hammer/driver has the Hammer function, so
> combining with the Reverse function, it would additionally help?

No the hammer function will not help.

A [screw extractor set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GZ17QD9) is far better then a reverse drill bit.

[How to use a screw extractor.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK32YsQNss8)

Comment: Thanks Alaska Man! Your explanations make sense! I suppose while the normal drill bit does not work, as it does not grab/cut into the stripped head, it may, in the process "loosen" up the stripped screw, so that additional methods may help? E,g. cutting the head to make a flat head to chisel it counterclockwise, heating it up with a heat gun, using a visegrip pliers ... etc Again, the fact is still true, normal bit does not cut into the surface of the stripped head!

Comment: There is no point in  using the reverse  bit if you can get a pair of vise grips on it.

Comment: I would respectfully/gently disagree: a reverse drill bit, followed by an extractor if the drill alone didn't do the job, is ideal! In fact to my eye it looks like the drill-end of the drill-and-extractor set linked in your answer is a left-hand drill.